# Detect when BlackBerry trackball/pad is being pressed?

Tags: java, events, blackberry, trackball

I would like to be able to do a "push-to-activate" style interaction with the trackball. That is, I would like an event notification at the beginning and end of the push. At the moment, using the code below, I can only get an event when the trackball/pad is let go.

```
/**
 * listen for clicks
 */
public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
{
    System.out.println("click (" + status + "," + time + ")");

    return super.navigationClick(status, time);
}
```

```
/**
 * listen for movement
 */
public boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time)
{
    System.out.println("move (" + dx + "," + dy + "," + status + "," + time + ")");

    return super.navigationMovement(dx, dy, status, time);
}
```

Is there an event that fires when I first press a button?

Comment: Could you share more what are you going to do with this event? Also what is your os target version?

Comment: I'm aiming at 4.6 right now. I just want to do a push-to-talk interaction, to record audio.

Comment: You can use `navigationClick` and `navigationUnclick`. Check API, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html

Comment: Do you have an example of `navigationClick` firing when the button is pressed *down*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was that it was only ever a problem in the simulator.

It's now working on a physical device and the `navigationClick(..)` and `navigationUnclick(..)` methods do exactly what they claim. They're basically button down and button up events for the trackball/pad.